# LoadError when called rake task with RAILS_ENV=test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I am using Ruby 2.1.1 and rails-4.1.0 with Spring.

I cannot launch rake with RAILS_ENV=test attribute. For some reasons rake command

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate
```

lead to the following error:

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/user/rbpr/getLead/db:migrate (LoadError)
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

My Rakfefile was not changed, it is default:

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
GetLead::Application.load_tasks
```

With RAILS_ENV=development and RAILS_ENV=production I have no LoadErrors. 
How can I catch this bug?

**UPDATE**

I have installed test DB and I have no pending migrations (all migrations are in status up for RAILS_ENV=test).

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: pgdb_getlead_test
  pool: 15
  username: ***
  password: ***
```

I have update RSpec, but still have the same error:

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/user/rbpr/getLead/db:reset (LoadError)
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:886:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:886:in `each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:886:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:90:in `run'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

The same with `rake db:test:prepare`:

```
WARNING: db:test:prepare is deprecated. The Rails test helper now maintains your test schema automatically, see the release notes for details.
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/user/rbpr/getLead/db:test:prepare (LoadError)
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:886:in `block in load_spec_files'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:886:in `each'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:886:in `load_spec_files'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:90:in `run'
  from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.0.beta1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Here is [source code](https://github.com/DavydenkovM/GetLead) where this error occurred

**FINAL UPDATE**

The problem was with the Gemfile and gems for testing in development group, many thanks for your attention.

Comment: try this `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`

Comment: have you defined db for test environment in configs?

Comment: `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` returns me the same error

Comment: Why do you need to migrate in test env? `rake db:test:prepare` does everything necessary, doesn't it?

Comment: I have LoadError with all rake tasks with RAILS_ENV=test. For example rake db:populate also returns this error. I would like to understand why I have this error.

Comment: I'm not sure why rake is trying to load the command you pass to it as a file. You might try updating rvm and reinstalling the rails gem.

Comment: I have tried `rvm get stable` and `reinstalling rails` and still have LoadError

Comment: i know the reason why it occurred but don't know the solution. if I found some solution I will answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the Gemfile and the grouping of certain gems to also load in development environment. If they're testing gems, keep them in group :test unless absolutely necessary to move them to development, like `factory_gril_rails` in example. So having,

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0.beta'
  ...
```

instead of:

```
group :development, :test do 
  gem 'rspec'
  ...
```

worked for me on my machine cloning your project. Hope this helps, give it a try.

p.s: there is also an old issue reported earlier [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7906).

Also, I think you'll not have to require factory_girl_rails in you Gemfile like:

```
gem 'factory_girl_rails', require: false
```

And then require it in your spec_helper:

```
require 'factory_girl_rails'
```

This way you're using this gem but you don't need to require it in other places than spec_helper.rb

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error message, it says

> WARNING: db:test:prepare is deprecated. The Rails test helper now maintains your test schema automatically, see the release notes for details.

In Rails 4.1+, they deprecated db:test:prepare with that message

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23351832/3148502)